# InvalidArgumentException in AuthManager.php line 86: Auth guard [users] is not defined

Tags: laravel-5

I am facing this issues with laravel 5.2, I am using multiple auth with different tables ( admins , users )  with admin section login it works correctly , with user login it gives me this error ?

Answer (score 1):

Add configured in your app/auth.php config file.

like

return [ 'defaults' => [ 'guard' => 'admin', 'passwords' => 'admin',], 'guards' => [ 'admin' => [ 'driver' => 'session', 'provider' => 'admin', ]], 'providers' => [ 'admin' => [ 'driver' => 'eloquent', 'model' => App\User::class, ],], 'passwords' => [ 'admin' => [ 'provider' => 'admin', 'email' => 'auth.emails.password', 'table' => 'password_resets', 'expire' => 60,],] ]